# Changing content of html if it matches a string

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to use an if statement to check if a piece of html equals a string, and if it does replace it. So far the payment method will get changed to Pending payment but the new paragraph element won't be. opaymethod changes dynamically dependent on how a customer has paid for an item.

html

```
<div class="label">Payment Type:</div>
    <div class="text" id="paymentMethod">[opaymethod]</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
<div class="element"></div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var doc = document.getElementById('paymentMethod').innerHTML;
  var res = doc.replace("Account customers", "Payment pending");

  document.getElementById("paymentMethod").innerHTML = res;


  if(document.getElementById('paymentMethod').innerHTML === 'Payment pending'){

    document.getElementById('element').append("<p>Payment Options: Bank payment</p>");
     console.log("inserted");
  }
  else
     console.log("not inserted");    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
<div class="label">Payment Type:</div>
<div class="text" id="paymentMethod">Payment pending</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="element" id="element"></div>

<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e){
        var paymentMethodElement = document.getElementById('paymentMethod');
        var elementElement = document.getElementById('element');
        paymentMethodElement.innerHTML = "Account customers";

        if( paymentMethodElement.innerHTML == "Account customers" ){
            alert('Payment method == Account customers!');
            elementElement.innerHTML = "<p>Payment Options: Bank payment</p>";

        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That's brilliant, the one issue is it's does it for all payment types i only want it for when that payment method is equal to account customers

Comment: @JohnDoi I'll update the answer accordingly. EDIT: I've also updated your "default text" to `Payment pending`, since that seems to be your initial state.

Comment: Thankyou for the advice. My issue is the id=paymenetMethod  changes dynamically so it could be range of different options. I can't force that to be pending payment. I need to test if that's account customers and only if it's that, replace otherwise leave alone to be whatever it needs to be.

Comment: @JohnDoi What are the possible values for the element? Also, it might be an idea to use data-attributes for this case. Also, are you working with PHP? A much better solution is to change your HTML output from PHP.

Comment: By id i was meaning just the variable [opaymethod], this changes dyanmically hence why i'm testing it for a certain string. I can get that to replace but i can#t get the if statement in my OP to work.

Comment: Unfortunately because my web store is on a hosting platform, they restrict me to using javascript only.

Comment: Okay, so in that case is you only need to add some more `if statements` with all your possible outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

When you do append, you are looking for the element by ID and if you repair the element has no ID but yes class.

Change

```
<div class="element" id="element"></div>
```